# Is it possible to include a dynamic library in a static library?

Tags: c++, gcc

I have a static library in Linux that depends on some dynamic libraries (GL and SDL2). At link time, I want those to link automatically without needing to pass more arguments to the linker (gcc in my case). I saw a solution that adds a special file into the library named __.LIBDEP by passing -l to ar but it's not an elegant solution as it adds more arguments when linking ([hint the dynamic library dependencies in the archive file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52730365/hint-the-dynamic-library-dependencies-in-the-archive-file)).